# DateTime conversion from string

Tags: apex, datetime, string

I'm new to Salesforce development and not sure why when I read a database column as string my result in debug log is:

> 01/06/2016 10:09 AM

while when i change it to DateTime it becomes:

> 2016-01-06 15:09:00

Why is there difference in the two? Any insights will be helpful. Here is my code:

```
String lastRunTime = myFeature.getAttributeValue('MyDate');
DateTime testDate = DateTime.parse(lastRunTime);
System.Debug('----------------------------------------------' + testDate);
System.Debug('----------------------------------------------' + lastRunTime);
```

Comment: What is myFeature? I'm guessing an Dom.XmlNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having issues with time zone conversion. Try using `Datetime.newInstanceGmt` to get around them.

```
String lastRunTime = '01/06/2016';
Datetime lastRun = Datetime.parse(lastRunTime);
Datetime lastRunGmt = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(lastRun.date(), lastRun.time());
```

For me these result in:

```
lastRun: 2016-01-06 17:09:00
lastRunGmt: 2016-01-06 10:09:00
```